# How do I create a function in C sharp that removes Whitespaces from a string ? ??

Tags: c#, whitespace

I would really like a little help here .
So I want to create a function in C Sharp that checks for whitespaces in a string (in the beggininng, the middle , the end) and I don't have a clue on how to approach this matter ! :(

Comment: Look into [`string.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var input = "this is a test";
var output = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
System.Console.WriteLine(output); // thisisatest
```

Or this:

```
var output = string.Join(string.Empty, input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

If all you want to do is check if the string contains any white space characters, do this:

```
var hasWhiteSpace = input.Any(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this is

```
"Any string with spaces".Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to work with that - it is simple to write and handles not only spaces.

```
var stringWithoutWhiteSpace = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s*", string.Empty)
```

Notice though, that usually it is good idea to cache `Regex` with particular pattern, as it takes some time to construct it, so keeping it in a separate static variable might be good idea if it will be used more than once, something like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static WhiteSpaceRegex = new Regex(@"\s*");

    public static string WithoutWhitespace(this string input) 
    {
        return WhiteSpaceRegex.Replace(input, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is not right.

Comment: @kostasch. - I've fixed syntax

Comment: That's better that the +1. :)

Comment: Why using Regex when a simple `string.Replace` works fine? Looks like overkill IMO.

Comment: @ken2k - because you don't have to remember all the characters, that are considered whitespace, like many answers forgot that tab character is also whitespace :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string str = "This is an example";
string str2 = str.Replace(" ","");
```

Comment: I'd of argued that using string.Empty is a bit more explicit

Answer (score 1):

```
string pp = "12. Twi  iter    ";
      pp = pp.Replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
string pp = "12. Twi  iter    ";
string s1 = Regex.Replace(pp, @"[ ]", "");
```

Comment: won't work with tabs i think

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`String.TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx), [`String.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) and [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) like this?

```
string s = " SomeRandom Words";
Console.WriteLine("Does Whitespace at the end? {0}", s != s.TrimEnd());
Console.WriteLine("Does Whitespace at the begining? {0}", s != s.TrimStart());
Console.WriteLine("Does Contains whitespace? {0}", s.Contains(" "));
```

Output will be;

```
Does Whitespace at the end? False
Does Whitespace at the begining? True
Does Contains whitespace? True
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/dRaEEk).

Comment: Why not just `char.IsWhiteSpace(s[0])` / `char.IsWhiteSpace(s[s.Length - 1])`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Of course `char.IsWhiteSpace` is another option also. I think using string methods is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Trim()
 TrimLeft()
 TrimRight()

String X=" Abc Def " ;

STring leftremoved = TrimLeft(x) ;

String rightremoved = TrimRight(x) ;

and use forloops to find for the middel space like by converting into charArray

rightRemoved.toCharArray();

int count = 0;

Char[] result ;
foreach(char s in rightremove.toCharArray())
{

if(s=='')
{
continue;

}
else
{

result[count] = s;

}

count ++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

made a function like...

```
public string clearSpace(string strParam)
{
  string s = strParam.Trim();
  s.Replace(" ","");
  return s;
}
```

you can use this function like....

```
string s = " hey    who    am   i  ?   ";
string s2=clearSpace(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

The [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class has a method called [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx). Check that out. It can substitute an empty string for spaces, achieving what you want. The [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method, on the other hand, will remove white spaces only from the beginning and the end of the string. Might also help you. There are also methods from trimming only the start or the end of the string.

- If you want to remove spaces from the start only, use [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx);
- If you want to remove spaces from the end, use [TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx);
- If you want to remove spaces at the start and the end, [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) will do that;
- If you want to remove from the middle only, you'll have to come up with some logic to remove all spaces, then reinserting those at the start and the end.