# Remove whitespaces in c# without any built in functions

Tags: c#

Hi I am a beginner in C# and I was trying to remove the whitespaces in a string.
I use the following code:

```
public String RemoveSpace(string str1)
{

    char[] source = str1.ToCharArray();

    int oldIndex = 0;
    int newIndex = 0;
    while (oldIndex < source.Length)
    {
        if (source[oldIndex] != ' ' && source[oldIndex] != '\t')
        {
            source[newIndex] = source[oldIndex];
            newIndex++;
        }
        oldIndex++;
    }
    source[oldIndex] = '\0';
    return new String(source);

}
```

But the problem I'm facing is when I give the 
**input string as "H e l"** 
**the output shows "Hel l"**
which is because the at the last iteration `oldIndex` is at `arr[2]` being replaced by `arr[4]` and the last character 'l' is being left out. Can some one point out the mistake that is being done? 
Note: There should not be any use of Regex, trim or replace functions.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to say `source[newIndex] = '\0'`

Comment: @AndyG: That'll avoid an IndexOutOfRangeException, but it won't truncate the string.

Comment: The code induces lots of corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some key learning points:

- Incrementally concatenating strings is relatively slow. Since you know you're going to be doing a 'lot' (indeterminate) number of character-by-character operations, use a `char` array for the working string.
- The fastest way to iterate through characters is C# is to use the built-in string indexer.

If you need to check additional characters besides space, tab, carriage return, and line feed, then add additional conditions in the `if` statement:

```
public static string RemoveWhiteSpace(string input) {
    int len = input.Length;
    int ixOut = 0;
    char[] outBuffer = new char[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = input[i];
        if(!(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\r' || c == '\n')) 
            outBuffer[ixOut++] = c;
    } 
    return new string(outBuffer, 0, ixOut);
}
```

Comment: He's already doing both things mentioned in your bullet points.  `Array.Resize` is a workable way to trim the end, but it also will make an extra unneeded copy.

Comment: No, he's not doing the second thing. He's calling `ToCharArray`, which makes a new *copy* of all the characters in the input string. I directly index into the string, which returns the character without creating a char array (of the input).

Comment: True, but he isn't creating an *extra* array.  The result of `ToCharArray()` is his working array.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, good point. Incidentally your answer regarding the constructor taking the offset and length arguments is the more salient point, and I've upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @Joshua Honig: thanks a lot for your explanation and nice points on string manipulation.

Answer (score 6):

There's [a String constructor which allows you to control the length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx)

So just change the last line to

```
return new String(source, 0, newIndex);
```

Note that .NET doesn't care about NUL characters (strings can contain them just fine), so you can remove `source[oldIndex] = '\0';` since it's ineffective.

Comment: Even better.  By far the simplest change to the OPs original code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` for that:

```
var output = new string(input.Where(x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
```

Your mistake is you are removing the spaces but your source array still contains the remaining `chars`.Using that logic you will never get the correct result because you are not removing anything, you are just replacing the chars.After your `while` loop you can try this:

```
return new String(source.Take(newIndex+1).ToArray());
```

Using `Take` method get the subset of your source array and ignore the rest.

Here is another *alternative* way of doing this:

```
var output = string.Concat(input.Split());
```

Comment: This is homework. If OP is learning code, I dont think a linq request will help him.

Comment: @aloisdg: of course it's homework.  However we have absolutely no idea what the question is.  It might very well be: come up with a way to remove spaces from a string.  If so, then this answer and mine provide two alternatives that both use the power of the framework... without using regex, trim or replace

Comment: @aloisdg: I see your point, but it's best not to forget that answers on SO aren't solely for the benefit of the OP. An answer can add value for possible future readers too.

Comment: @Baldrick [Well](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+remove+whitespace) and we could mark it as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string).

Answer (score 1):

You should note that much depends on how you define "whitespace". Unicode and the CLR define whitespace as being [a rather exhaustive list of characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode): [`char.IsWhitespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) return true for quite a few characters.

The "classic" definition of whitespace are the following characters: HT, LF, VT, FF, CR and SP (and some might include BS as well).

Myself, I'd probably do something like this:

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
  public static string StripWhitespace( this string s )
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
    foreach ( char c in s )
    {
      switch ( c )
      {
    //case '\b' : continue ; // U+0008, BS uncomment if you want this
      case '\t' : continue ; // U+0009, HT
      case '\n' : continue ; // U+000A, LF
      case '\v' : continue ; // U+000B, VT
      case '\f' : continue ; // U+000C, FF
      case '\r' : continue ; // U+000D, CR
      case ' '  : continue ; // U+0020, SP
      }
      sb.Append(c) ;
    }
    string stripped = sb.ToString() ;
    return stripped ;
  }
}
```

You could use your approach thusly. However, it's important to [READ THE DOCUMENTATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)): you'll note the use of a `string` constructor overload that lets you specify a range within an array as the initialization vector for the string:

```
public static string StripWhitespace( string s )
{
  char[] buf = s.ToCharArray() ;
  int j = 0 ; // target pointer
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < buf.Length ; ++i )
  {
    char c = buf[i] ;
    if ( !IsWs(c) )
    {
      buf[j++] = c ;
    }
  }
  string stripped = new string(buf,0,j) ;
  return stripped ;
}

private static bool IsWs( char c )
{
  bool ws = false ;
  switch ( c )
  {
//case '\b' : // U+0008, BS uncomment if you want BS as whitespace
  case '\t' : // U+0009, HT
  case '\n' : // U+000A, LF
  case '\v' : // U+000B, VT
  case '\f' : // U+000C, FF
  case '\r' : // U+000D, CR
  case ' '  : // U+0020, SP
    ws = true ;
    break ;
  }
  return ws ;
}
```

You could also use Linq, something like:

```
    public static string StripWhitespace( this string s )
    {
        return new string( s.Where( c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ).ToArray() ) ;
    }
```

Though, I'm willing to be that the Linq approach will be significantly slower than the other two. It's elegant, though.