# Remove white space from xml response

Tags: c#, xml

Below is the sample code for creation of xml.

```
var bpsResponseXml = new XElement("BPSResponse");         

bpsResponseXml.Add(new XElement("Response",
                                    new XElement("Code", "804"),
                                    new XElement("Text", "TagID value is not genuine")));

var outPutXml = bpsResponseXml.Value;
```

Current Output xml is shown below, as you can see there are spaces between the characters and words :

```
<BPSResponse>    <Response>      <Code>804</Code>      <Text>TagID value is not genuine.</Text>    </Response>  </BPSResponse>
```

Rather than above xml i want trimmed xml as below :

```
<BPSResponse><Response><Code>804</Code><Text>TagID value is not genuine.</Text></Response></BPSResponse>
```

Please help for the same!

Comment: Possible duplicate [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Comment: No, its not. Because, it also trims attribute value as well. i want <Text> TagID value is not genuine</Text> as output. your suggession gives me <Text>TagIDvalueisnotgenuine.</Text> as output.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're getting the XML out - just using the `Value` property will only give you the text content anyway. If you're using `Save`, you can just specify `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting`.

Comment: var outPutXml = bpsResponseXml.ToString();

Comment: You're probably looking for this [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb551415.aspx) overload, which takes a [SaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx) parameter. In your case `DisableFormatting`.

Comment: @Corak: Nice - I hadn't spotted there's an overload of `ToString` for that as well as `Save`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is Sample code which will resolve issue.

```
var bpsResponseXml = new XElement("BPSResponse");         

bpsResponseXml.Add(new XElement("Response",
                                    new XElement("Code", "804"),
                                    new XElement("Text", "TagID value is not genuine")));

var outPutXml = bpsResponseXml.ToString(System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```