# Trim() not working properly?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm building out a function to allow users to change their email address and if they accidentally put in a whitespace before or after, I need to trim it so the regex doesn't complain. It doesn't seem to work in the place I have it (the string remains exactly the same) but I'm not sure why.
This is in my controller:

```
public ActionResult ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailVM vm)
        {
            try
            {
                if (UserManager.EmailAvail(new EmailRequest
                {
                    Email = vm.EmailAddress.Trim()
                }))
                else//...etc etc
```

I was thinking I'd possibly need to put .trim() in the getter or setter of the email address but I'm not sure of the proper syntax.

Comment: Please elaborate about 'not working properly'. What do you expect it to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: What do you expect this to be doing that it's not?

Comment: Trim will only remove trailing or leading whitespace. If you want to remove all whitespace, use replace.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string

Comment: It doesn't affect the input at all. So if the user enters "   xyz@test.com    " (with whitespace before and after), it will still leave all of the extra whitespaces

Comment: Trim doesn't mutate the string. It returns a new string that has been trimmed. You've only passed the trimmed string into `EmailAvailForReg`. `UpdateEmail` is not going to have the trimmed string because the `EmailAddress` property on `viewModel` wasn't changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) is read only - you cannot change the value by calling anything on it, and instead these methods return new values with the desired changes, including `.Trim`; if you wish to change `viewModel.EmailAddress` you should assign the result of `Trim()` to that same variable:

EDIT: At some point, I would like to see a `.=` operator, since this kind of "mutate and save" comes up surprisingly often

```
viewModel.EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress.Trim()
```