# Best way to remove duplicate strings with different spacing?

Tags: c#, string, duplicates

I have a list of strings that contain some duplicates. They are not EXACT duplicates as some contain spaces in different locations. Example of a list:

```
best shoes for flat feet
bestshoes for flat feet
best shoesfor flatfeet
best shoes for flatfeet
```

Now what I would like to do is remove all these duplicate strings, keeping only the one with the MOST spaces (we will assume this is the correct spacing).

Can anyone recommend me a way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you are facing the problem you never solved before - try to solve it in the most naive way. Say, exactly the same way you would solve it if you were given 200 such strings and a piece of paper.

Comment: How do you resolve ties, when the same number of spaces appears at different places? E.g. `a..b.c` vs. `a.b..c` (I use dots in place of spaces to make them visible). Which one would you like to pick?

Comment: I would make a class that holds your string as a prop, and make a list of lists of ints, each list of ints is the indices of space locations of one mutation of your string, but I think it'll be beneficial for a large number of mutations of your string

Comment: Naively, you simply said "Give me the longest string of a list of strings"...are you SURE that is what you desire? THAT seems easy

Comment: You're right when you look at it that way that's all it is. I was overthinking something extremely simple it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Start by constructing a "canonical" version from each string by removing all spaces ([here is how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6219454/335858))
- Use canonical version as a key to group your strings
- Pick the longest string among the ones in the same group

You can do it with LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
var res = orig
    .GroupBy(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", ""))
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count(c => c==' ')).First()` would be more expressive (as it matches exact requirement), but indeed it is the same as  `s => s.Length` as the difference is only in spaces.