# Removing all whitespace from a list C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm reading all the lines from a text file into a list called 'masterToken', i'm trying to remove all the whitespace that will be in the list (all the spaces that were in the text file). `masterToken = masterToken.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();` is what i'm trying to use currently, it isn't working.

What is wrong with `masterToken = masterToken.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();` and/or is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Thanks

```
public static void Lex()
{        
  List<string> masterToken = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Theo\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Interpreter\\test.txt").ToList();

  foreach (var item in masterToken)
  {
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
  }

  masterToken = masterToken.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();

  Console.WriteLine("");

  foreach (var item in masterToken)
  {
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It will **only get rid of empty lines** as you are iterating over each line. You are not very clear in your question if you want to actually remove every white space everywhere so that words would justruntogetherlikethis.

Comment: not sure why it isnt working. I did a test using the same linq statement and it gave me a new list with no whitespace entries. Unless you want it to eliminate any white space from any entries, and not just the entries that have only whitespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Comment: The code you have removes all blank lines from the file. Your question is unclear. Are you trying to remove all whitespace characters completely?

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace each sequence of whitespaces `\s+` with empty string. Use this method to produce new strings and save results to list:

```
masterToken = masterToken.Select(t => Regex.Replace(t, @"\s+", "")).ToList();
```

Note that if you want to remove only leading and trailing whitespaces, then it's better to use [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
masterToken = masterToken.Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList();
```

And keep in mind that neither `Trim` nor `Replace` will not modify original string - all these methods return new string instances.

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line:

```
masterToken = masterToken.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

By this:

```
masterToken.ForEach(s => s = s.Replace(" ",""));
```

Comment: Nope, list will stay unchanged

Comment: also, `.Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Try regex

```
Regex.Replace(item,@"\s+","");
```