# Eliminating white spaces in strings

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a efficient way for removing all of the white spaces in an string.
I have checked replace (replace(' ','')) but I'm looking for a more efficient way.
I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Comment: Do you want to remove whitespace globally? then you can be used trim model binder from link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1734025/9334498

Comment: are you using EntityFramwork??

Comment: Use the dupe Luke, it has many answers. Answers with benchmark of other answer. It doesn't blindly claim red car  are faster. It provides tests cases and benchmark.

Comment: Yo have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347881/8024781) a list of ways of replacing whites, with a test class that measures the time it takes for each solution

Answer (score 0):

You may use Regular Expression.

For example:

```
var result=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");
```

Input is your string

See more [Removing whitespaces using C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/removing-whitespaces-using-chash-regex)

Comment: "must" is a strong word here. You _can_. Alternatively, you could also use something like `new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())`. Since Regex isn't magic, it _probably_ does something very similar to that.

Comment: thanks you for comment, i already edit @Corak