# luhn algorithm with spaced strings as input c#

Tags: c#, trim, luhn

Trying to implement a luhn algorithm but with a spaced string as an input.
I've tried Linq, some predefined string functions that might be directly related to it (Trim(), Replace()) but it dosen't print out the correct answer

Here's my code:

```
static bool checkCard(string cardNo)    
{   
    
    
    int[] cardInt = new int[cardNo.Length];
    for(int i = 0;i < cardNo.Length; i++){
        cardInt[i] = (int)(cardNo[i]);
    }
    for(int i = cardNo.Length - 2;i >= 0;i-=2){
        int temporaryValue = cardInt[i];
        temporaryValue*=2;
        if(temporaryValue > 9){
            temporaryValue = temporaryValue % 10 +1;
        }
        cardInt[i] = temporaryValue;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<cardNo.Length;i++){
        sum+=cardInt[i];
    }
    if(sum % 10 == 0){
        return true;
    }
        
    return false;
    
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string card = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (checkCard(card))
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
        else
        Console.WriteLine("NO");
        
    }

}
```

Input : 4556 7375 8689 9855

The output must be "YES" But it prints "NO" instead
What can I edit so I get rid of this error?

Comment: `(int)(cardNo[i])` is not digit ... it's ascii/char value so for example `'1' ` is `49`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-5.0 to check if its a digit and if you want the int value you'll either need to convert to string first or use int.Parse

Comment: What about `cardNo = cardNo.Replace(" ", "");`? (Assuming you want to get rid of every spaces, and spaces can be anywhere)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Comment: @gunr2171, nope, still having the same problem

Comment: What others said is that *casting* - `(int)c` - is different from *parsing* - `int.Parse(c)`. Here is why your result is different from what you expected.

Comment: @Rafalon, you get cs1503 error there

Comment: `int.Parse(c.ToString())` if you prefer, whatever

Answer (score 0):

In your case i don't see why you can't just use char.IsDigit() seeing as credit card numbers aren't alphanumeric
here a short linq example:

```
        var digitsOnly = cardNo.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray();
        int[] integersArray = digitsOnly.Select( x = int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

btw if you cast char to int you'll get its ASCII intvalue so 0 would be 48, 1 is 49 etc.

Answer (score 0):

the right answer to this problem was proposed by @Rafalon

Adding a Replace(" ", "") function after every string reading